# Booking system to take a deposit and then final amount at a later date

Tags: paypal

This is more of a question regarding flow than code.

I'm currently working on a booking website for a holiday home. I've implemented a booking system which currently takes full payment at the time of booking. This uses PayPal REST API. It works fine no problems code-wise.

However my client would like the system to take a deposit when booking (20%) of the total. Then take the remaining amount later on (through the site). This seems strange to me and I've never used a website which does this so I'm not sure what the flow should be.

The only way I can think of achieving this is that the user has to come to the website at some point in the future to pay the remaining amount. I could send them email reminders but it seems a bit awkward to do that.

Has anyone done anything like this in the past?

Answer (score 0):

In order to take the money later, you need to store the credit card data in your system, which is not quite legal unless you are authorized payment service provider (and I'm almost sure you're not). 
We have the same case in our reservation system. Generally, you'd allow credit card payment only for deposit, and later final amount is paid via bank transfer or cash, for example, and has to be settled manually by an operator.

Your idea is not bad, however. You could inform the user about the final amount and due date in the booking confirmation email and later on send them reminders.

Comment: Cheers for your answer. I'm not sure whether my client would want to do part manually and part through the website. I will run that option past them though.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize reference transactions to handle this without storing/saving any billing information on your server.

Reference transactions can be used in [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) as well as with [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-referenceTransactions-curl-etc/).

Basically, the way it'll work is that you can process the original 20% and then you'll save that transaction ID in your database.  Once you're ready to process the remaining amount you just make a call to [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) and supply the original transaction ID along with the new amount to charge.  PayPal will then charge this new amount using the billing information that they have saved on their server.

Comment: That sounds like a good route to follow. I noticed that the PayPal REST API has an invoice mechanism in which you can create the invoice, PayPal sends it to the user, who then logs into PayPal and pays it off. Link here for anyone stumbling onto this thread: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/invoicing/